# How to get current DateTime from client?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I want to show current client DateTime with a blazor component.

Which time does next code present?

```
<div>@DateTime.Now</div>
```

I think it will be server time. How can I get client OS time?

Comment: You can take a look at this nuget package: https://github.com/jsakamoto/Toolbelt.Blazor.TimeZoneKit

Comment: @RahulSharma, it is for [tag:blazor-client-side]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**First Solution:**

---

using  [Blazored.Localisation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Blazored.Localisation/) nuget package

in Package Manager Console

```
Install-Package Blazored.Localisation
```

in Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddBlazoredLocalisation(); // This adds the IBrowserDateTimeProvider to the DI container
}
```

and in your view

```
@inject Blazored.Localisation.Services.IBrowserDateTimeProvider browserDateTimeProvider
@page "/"

<p>The current local time is: <strong>@currentLocalTime</strong></p>

@code {

    string currentLocalTime = "";

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender) // Remove the firstRender check if you want the current local time displayed to continuously update.
        {   // Leave the above firstRender check in place to ensure that the call to StateHasChanged() does not trigger an endless update loop.
            var browserDateTime = await browserDateTimeProvider.GetInstance();
            currentLocalTime = browserDateTime.Now.ToString();
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Second Solution:**

---

like @Ibrahem Uwk said, add function in Separate JavaScript file and include it in _Host.cshtml or any file but **not .razor** file

Code in JavaScript file

```
function getClientDate() {
var d = new Date();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;
}
```

and then call the function in your View

```
@page "/"
@inject IJSRuntime jsRuntime


...

<p id="demo"></p>

...

@code {
protected async override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
    // call your JS here
    JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("getClientDate");
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The best and most reliable way to get the timezone from the client is to ask them for it. Usually you give your user's a "profile" page where they can update things like timezones, currency and formatting. I would suggest this as a more robust solution.

Answer (score 0):

U can use Js as following for example :

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var d = new Date();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;
</script>
```

And this will run in user side and get the local time for user

Comment: I get compile-time error  `Script tags should not be placed inside components because they cannot be updated dynamically. To fix this, move the script tag to the 'index.html' file or another static location.`

Comment: inline javascript in .razor component will not work in Blazor

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Blazor server side then check out [Blazor Time](https://github.com/dustout/BlazorTime) (it also works with webassembly).

It lets you convert to local by introducing a `<ToLocal>` razor component.

`<ToLocal DateTime="testUtcTime" Format="ddd mmm dd yyyy HH:MM:ss"></ToLocal>`

Answer (score -3):

For getting the client os time , you have to use TimeZone or you can use toLocaleDateString() . You can use either below code

```
<div>@DateTime.Now.toLocaleDateString()</div>
```

or

```
<div>@new Date().toLocaleDateString()</div>
```

It may resolve your issue.

Comment: did you mean I have to create a javascript wrapper?